# Connection between arduino(wifi shield) and PC locally, with router

Tags: sockets, arduino, port

I want to connect my PC-with-arduino (server client) with TCP/IP socket. In my PC i have written java code to make this happen. My questions are : I have to make port forwarding to my router? If yes, i will pass the port socket(client-server) into router? I have the zte zxv10 h108l  router and i can't find any instructions about port forwarding for this model!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say **locally**, which means you do not need any port forwarding.  All your devices are on the same subnet, and you can directly open connections with each other.

Port forwarding would only be necessary if something outside you network wants to open a connection to something inside.  Basically, if something on the WAN side of the router wants to open a connection to something on the LAN side.  For example, you at a coffee shop on your laptop connecting to Arduino in your house.

Note that the reverse does not hold: something on the LAN side can open a connection to something on the WAN side with no port forwarding -- that is the NAT function of the router and is always active.  For example, that is how your computer connects to stackoverflow with no special configuration on the router.